# how to make dynamic textarea autogrow on typing?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am creating textareas dynamically in jquery mobile. But the problem is dynamic textarea doesnt grow automatically on typing while the textarea created statically is autogrowing on typing.. can someone tell me how to implement autogrowing of dynamically created textareas. Thanks in advance

Comment: http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/autogrowtextarea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this just after you add the textarea to the DOM:

```
$("#pageId").trigger('create');//id of the the data-role="page" div in which you are dynamically adding the texarea.
```

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with this question.

Comment: also can you tell how to limit the growing of textarea on typing?? I tried using max-height property but no use...the textarea keeps on growing more than the page-height.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery [autogrow](http://plugins.jquery.com/autogrow/) plugin for this.

```
$(function() {
    $('#yourtextarea').autogrow();
});
```

Comment: its not working.. i tried 
$(function() { $('#yourtextarea').autogrow(); });
also
$(function() {    $('#yourtextarea').autosize();});